# how to count both used and unused per usage per tag in one oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a DB table of which the name is "USAGE", with these columns :

1) "USAGE_NAME", the possible values for it are: A, B.

2) "TAG", the possible value for it are:  a) it could be A1, A2,or A3, if the "USAGE_NAME" is A; b) it would be B1, B2, or B3, if the USAGE_NAME is B.

3) "USED", it could either be a null value (USED) or an un-null value(USED).

I want to have one SQL to return back both used and unused COUNT, per each TAG, per each USAGE_NAME.

The way I have implemented is too wordy, does someone have a simple solution ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: *it could either be a null value (USED) or an un-null value(USED)* - seems like a typo. Which one is used and which unused?

Answer (score 0):

Group by the `tag` and use conditional aggregation

```
select tag, 
       sum(case when used is null then 1 else 0 end) as unused_cnt,
       count(used) as used_cnt,
       count(*) as total_cnt
from usage
group by tag
```

Since `count()` counts only non-null values you can use it to get used counts.

Comment: Thanks. This looks much better than what I have done.